# How to avoid malicious use of download attribute?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql-server, server

For example, using Developer tools in Chrome, it is possible to change the target of any link on a page to index.php and add download attribute to that link. Then just clicking that link, download of index.php is executed - providing, that index.php exists on the website, and in the same directory as the page I am on. Taking into account the broad use of PHP in the world (over 80% of websites), I guess that every second website contains index.php. In fact, I tried and downloaded a few files from random websites - owners do not know, but they are lucky that I do not intend to misuse their data. In almost every case of the successfully downloaded index.php, I also figured out a way to find credentials to their MySQL database (if that was in use). 
Now I am doing my website and want to avoid this. How is it done? I buy web hosting and have access to php.ini. Thak you.

Comment: If the credentials to the database are in the page that the issue. The is a horrible way to build any application. Those types of things should always be in a config or ini file. This makes it a single location to change and you can also prevent serving that type of file in iis or apache quite easily.

Comment: Develop your site as if it's open source. Secrets should be stored in files which are not accessible.

Comment: So you found a way to download index.php as download... Do you really see unparsed php code?

Answer (score 3):

Php is executed server side and will never be able to be downloaded or accessible from front facing client side. You may be seeing the index.php code but that will only be showing the HTML, no actual php, So you do not need to worry about this.
But obviously make sure that no important information such as usernames or passwords are displayed on your html as that is accessible to everyone, any javascript can also been seen using dev tools.